# Is there a better way to do this in R?

Tags: r, database, sorting

My friend today gave me a file, which looks like this:

```
     ID         genotype snp.id

1  PT86         CA      192902098
2   PT8         CA      192902098
3  PT33         TC      191571437
4  PT27         GA      191026838
5   PT2         TG      188482874
6   PT1         GC      186443061
7  PT70         GC      186443061
8  PT59         GA      185444226
9  PT48         GA      185152161
10 PT54         GA      185152161
11 PT18         GA      185152161
12 PT27         GA      185152161
```

actually the data had nearly 1000 rows, i am showing only a sample of 12 rows here.

He asked me if i can convert this file in to format like this:

```
   id rs185152161 rs185444226 rs186443061 rs188482874 rs191026838 rs191571437 rs192902098
1   PT1        <NA>        <NA>         GC         <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
2  PT18         GA         <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
3   PT2        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>         TG         <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
and so on....
```

Here's how i did this.

First I took the list of snp.ids i need to extract

```
snp.ids=data.frame(table(raw$snp.id))[,1]
```

Then I extracted subsets of the data with each snp.id and placed inside a matrix of lists.

```
mat=matrix(list(),ncol=1,nrow=13)
for (i in 1:7) { 
    mat[[i,1]]=subset(raw,snp.id==snpids[[i]])[,1:2] 
    names(mat[[i,1]])=c('id',paste("rs",snpids[[i]],sep=""))
    }
```

Then i merged all the the dataframes i extracted.

```
df1= Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,all=T),mat[1:7,1])
df2=df1[!duplicated(df1$id),]
```

so the data looks like

```
     id rs185152161 rs185444226 rs186443061 rs188482874 rs191026838 rs191571437 rs192902098
1   PT1        <NA>        <NA>         GC         <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
2  PT18         GA         <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
3   PT2        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>         TG         <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
4  PT27         GA         <NA>        <NA>        <NA>         GA         <NA>        <NA>
5  PT33        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>         TC         <NA>
6  PT48         GA         <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
7  PT54         GA         <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
8  PT59        <NA>         GA         <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
9  PT70        <NA>        <NA>         GC         <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
10  PT8        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>         CA 
11 PT86        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>         CA
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to do this without using these loop functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For going from long to wide format, there is always `reshape`.

```
library(reshape)
reshape(data, idvar = "ID", timevar = "snp.id", direction = "wide")
```

resulting in this:

```
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| ID   | genotype.192902098 | genotype.191571437 | genotype.191026838 | genotype.188482874 | genotype.186443061 | genotype.185444226 | genotype.185152161 |
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| PT86 | CA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 |
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| PT8  | CA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 |
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| PT33 | NA                 | TC                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 |
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| PT27 | NA                 | NA                 | GA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | GA                 |
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| PT2  | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | TG                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 |
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| PT1  | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | GC                 | NA                 | NA                 |
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| PT70 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | GC                 | NA                 | NA                 |
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| PT59 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | GA                 | NA                 |
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| PT48 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | GA                 |
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| PT54 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | GA                 |
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| PT18 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | NA                 | GA                 |
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Try: (`dat` is the dataset)

```
library(reshape2)
res <- dcast(dat, ID~snp.id, value.var="genotype")
colnames(res)[-1] <- paste0("rs", colnames(res)[-1])
head(res,3)
#    ID rs185152161 rs185444226 rs186443061 rs188482874 rs191026838 rs191571437
#1  PT1        <NA>        <NA>          GC        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
#2 PT18          GA        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
#3  PT2        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>          TG        <NA>        <NA>
#  rs192902098
#1        <NA>
#2        <NA>
#3        <NA>
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c("PT86", "PT8", "PT33", "PT27", "PT2", "PT1", 
"PT70", "PT59", "PT48", "PT54", "PT18", "PT27"), genotype = c("CA", 
"CA", "TC", "GA", "TG", "GC", "GC", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA"
), snp.id = c(192902098L, 192902098L, 191571437L, 191026838L, 
188482874L, 186443061L, 186443061L, 185444226L, 185152161L, 185152161L, 
185152161L, 185152161L)), .Names = c("ID", "genotype", "snp.id"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```

#### Update

If your data has multiple entries for each combination

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c("PT86", "PT8", "PT33", "PT27", "PT2", "PT1", 
"PT70", "PT59", "PT48", "PT54", "PT18", "PT27", "PT27"), genotype = c("CA", 
"CA", "TC", "GA", "TG", "GC", "GC", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", 
"GC"), snp.id = c(192902098L, 192902098L, 191571437L, 191026838L, 
188482874L, 186443061L, 186443061L, 185444226L, 185152161L, 185152161L, 
185152161L, 185152161L, 185152161L)), .Names = c("ID", "genotype", 
"snp.id"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"))


dcast(dat, ID~snp.id, value.var="genotype") #able to reproduce the problem
#Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
#----------------------------------
```

Create an `index` for unique combinations

```
dat$indx <- with(dat, ave(seq_along(ID), ID, FUN=seq_along))
dcast(dat, ID+indx~snp.id, value.var="genotype")[,-2]
```

Comment: I am getting numbers instead of genotypes in genotype column. Also I get the following warning message: "Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length"

Comment: @dOctOr  It could be because there are multiple entries for each combination.  My code was based on the example you provided.  Could you show a very small example data that shows the warning message?

Comment: @dOctOr I updated for cases with multiple entries per combination